# Topology of fibers of operators under C^{\infty} convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-topology, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

A smooth family of maps $f_t : L^2 (\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is given, with $t \in (0,1]$. Suppose that when $t \rightarrow 0$ the family restricted to balls of given radius converges in the $C^{\infty}$ topology to a map $\hat{f}$. Is there something known to be true about the relations between the fibers of $\hat{f}$ and the fibers of $f_t$ as $t \rightarrow 0$?